# finding the Lipschitz condition for two IVP's?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

***The First one***
$$\frac{du}{dt}=u^{1/3},\quad u(0)=0.$$
I showed that the above IVP does not satisfy the Lipschitz condition. Then the question asked if the initial condition is changed to 
$$u(0)= u_0,\quad \text{where}\; u_0\neq 0$$
then the Lipschitz condition is satisfied ? I am not sure about this part.

***The Second one*** 
$$\frac{du}{dt}=u^{4/3}, \quad u(t_0)=u_0.$$

Here the function $u^{4/3}$ being continuous assures us the existence of the solution but in order to get the uniqueness it needs to satisfy the Lipschitz condition which I tried but was unable to get to a decisive point.

How to show this satisfies the Lipschitz condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, note that the slope becomes unbounded at $0$, so as long as you can find an interval avoiding $0$, you may make sure that the vector field is Lipschitz. Indeed, by the mean value theorem, 
$$
|u_1^{1/3}-u_2^{1/3}|=|u_1-u_2|\frac{1}{3c^{2/3}}
$$
for $c$ between $u_1$ and $u_2$. Provided we have $u(0)=u_0\ne 0$, we can make sure that $\frac{1}{3c^{2/3}}$ is bounded by a constant independent of the $u_1$ and $u_2$ we pick.

Indeed, suppose without a loss of generality that  $u(0)=u_0>0$, then for any $u_1,u_2$ inside $(u_0/2,+\infty)$ we have 
$$
|u_1^{1/3}-u_2^{1/3}|=|u_1-u_2|\frac{1}{3c^{2/3}}\leq |u_1-u_2|\frac{1}{3}\frac{2^{2/3}}{u_0^{2/3}}
$$
since $\frac{1}{c^{2/3}}$ is no larger than when $c$ is smallest. Thus, for nonzero $u(0)$, we can find an interval on which $f(t,u)=u^{1/3}$ is Lipschitz.

Can you apply similar analysis for the second problem?

Comment: I tried to apply $(a^3-b^3)=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$(also used this to show the 1st one is not Lipschitz) this to the 2nd problem to get 
$u_1^{4/3}-u_2^{4/3}=(u_1-u_2) *\frac{(u_1^2+u_2^2)*(u_1+u_2)}{u_1^{8/3}+(u1u2)^{4/3}+u_2^{8/3}}$  .Now what should I do ?